# Queuing Theory Algorithms to determine the next customer to be served

Tags: algorithm, queue, theory, priority-queue

I've been studying Queuing Theory and I have been searching for well known techniques/algorithms applied to customer queues for systems that can provide multiple services associated to the same queue. In other words, algorithms where the queue discipline isn't a pure FIFO discipline.

For example, the system provides the service A, B and C and each service may have a priority of service time: A (50%), B(30%) and C(20%). I'd like to find articles or books that focus on these scenarios and how to do a fair management of the queue to serve customers for real world scenarios.

I'm interested mostly in M/M/s queues.

UPDATE: I've been searching a lot on this subject and I've been reading about Weighted Fair Queuing and Start-Time Fair Queuing. Does anyone know of implementations or procedures describing these algorithms? I'm not working with routers or any network related device. I'm doing a software for customer attendance. I don't need to deal with bursts of packets and such things.

Best regards,
Manuel Felício.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should be searching for `queueing systems with admission policies`. I would begin with a google scholar search for the same. Next, you could go deeper depending on what exactly you want to study. For instance, there is a large amount of literature on `achieveable performance` in queueing systems. See, for instance, [Characterization and Optimization of Achievable Performance in General Queueing Systems](http://www.jstor.org/stable/171318). In such problems, an admission scheme is researched that will result in certain exogeneously specified soujourn/waiting times for different customer classes (or classes with priority as in your case). Although queueing theory has been studied for a long time, analytically tractable models are restricted to `M/M/s` models generally. Study of other models (especially `M/G/s` systems) usually requires simulation/approximations.

Comment: Thanks Tryer. I searched with some keywords you mentioned and found a nice article that might be helpful: http://www.cs.caltech.edu/~adamw/papers/multi2.pdf Anyway they refer to jobs instead of customers. The problem of queues applied to customers is that people who requests a ticket get angry when someone else requests a ticket for another service and enters service before them. This may occur, but not if the first guy is waiting a lot of time. Anyway I'd like to read about these scenarios in detail. I'm searching this kind of stuff.If you happen to know any info about this please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [WF2Q: worst-case fair weighted fair queueing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel2%2F3539%2F10628%2F00497885.pdf%3Farnumber%3D497885&authDecision=-203). However if you are planning to implement as a quick algo then you may want to consider WF2Q+.

EDIT
Additionally some of the book [resource](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lfGQBBK5zfcC&dq=M/M/s+queues&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. My only concern is that this theory usually refers to network packets. Is this suitable for customer queues?

Comment: I think it should be applicable here too, as customer arrival rate and there expected weighting time  should might fit well to Poisson distribution